# Jquery validating not empty and is URL in forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, url-validation

I'm using the following fiddle to create a form and check that both fields are not empty and that the second field is a valid URL.
http://jsfiddle.net/nc6NW/366/

```
<form method=post>
     <input type="text" id='first_name'>
     <input type="url" id='second_name'>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" disabled>
</form>

<script>
$(':text').keyup(function() {
     if($('#first_name').val() != "" && $('#second_name').val() != "") {
           $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
}    else {
           $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);   
     }
});

</script>
```

However it only works when you return to amend the first field after adding the URL

Comment: You are only executing your check (the fields are non-empty) when you have keyup on a text field. Your second field is of type url. So keyup on this box is not executing check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:text` is the issue.

Update your jQuery to the below

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
   if($('#first_name').val() != "" && $('#second_name').val() != "") {
      $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);   
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are listening to `':text'` keyup. Because your second input is an `'url'` type, it do not trigger the function.

That's why you have to go back to first input.

Answer (score 1):

The events are being triggered only on keyup of the first input field. Add a similar keyup event to the second field and it will work